# If a monarch does something illegal to take the throne, what would be the legal implications of prosecuting them for it?

Tags: immunity, monarchy, regicide

Assume that, in a modern kingdom, the Crown Prince murders the king. He technically becomes king, as he's the legal heir of the throne. Could the prince be prosecuted for that and denied the throne?

In 1648, the Parliamentarians were debating the charges to try Charles I for, and one of those that came up was a claim that he killed his father James. Would these kinds of cases mean that you could prosecute them on the grounds that they were not legitimately made king and this doesn't have sovereign immunity?

Edit: Not specific to a particular country. Nepal had a famous regicide in 2001. Also, the Kuwaiti Sheik just died. If that was caused by his brother who is now the Sheik shooting him for instance, that would also count.

Comment: This is a political question that doesn't really have a meaningful answer within the legal system.

Comment: I know of no murder of Queen Elisabeth II, then head of the house Saxe-Coburg and Gotha branch "Windsor" and ruler of Great Britain and the Commonwealth, that happened in 2001.

Comment: Well, then I guess we can assume he isn't talking about England.

Comment: I presume he _is_ talking about England (note the 1648 year kings' reference), and the "EG" stands for "e.g." which indicates that the scenario is hypothetical. Voting to reopen as this is a valid legal question, even though the answer may be arguable and unsettled.

Comment: I agree to the reopening, but the question should be improved. After all, killing a king to become king in his stead did happen in history numerous times.

Comment: "in a modern kingdom" there is no such thing as a default "modern kingdom", just as there is no default "modern democrary" as far as laws are concerned. Please state which kingdom you mean.

Comment: @nvoigt There aren't that many existing kingdoms (Wikipedia lists 32). I don't know whether the OP has a particular one in mind (maybe UK), but expecting answers for one of the current kingdoms is IMHO reasonable.

Comment: @PMF less, some of them are misclassified: Japan is by the Tenno being an emperor an Empire, not a kingdom. The vatican has no heir-apparent or designated-heir, and is elective anyway. Luxembourg is a Grand-Duchy/Erzherzogtum, which is below Kingdom in rank. Andorra is a principality with an ex-officio rulers, not a kingdom. The Emirates of Kuwait and Quatar are technically ruled by princes, not kings, and the rank of sultan isn't a king-title either but more akin to an emperor. - that would be malik. And then there's 15 personal unions under the GB-commonwealth crown.

Comment: @PMF Monacco is a Principality, Lichtenstein is a principality of slightly different level, The UAE have a primus-inter-pares president from the smaller emirates, Buthan has a Dragon-King which isn'T comparable with a kingdom, Malaysia is a constitutional monarch but not a king... That leaves 15 or 16 different monarchs of one or more kingdoms that carry the title of King. Of them only 2 are absolute, (Eswatini and Saudi Arabia) with two Sultanates (Brunei and Oman) joining them in absoluteness but of technically higher rank.

Comment: @Trish Ok, I see, it gets complicated. I don't know what the OP wants, but can we limit the question to the UK?

Comment: Clearly, this is a question about the Norwegian monarchy, despite the reference to the assassination of the King of Nepal, since the King of Norway hasn't been murdered by his son for a really long time, if ever.

Comment: @user6726 if anything, we can exclude Belgium, for that is currently ruled by a queen..

Comment: I would argue that Charles I wasn't even the rightful king. As far as I can tell the last legitimate king was murdered by William the Bastard in 1066. Everyone since then is an usurper.